# Is there any outage when you add a second region to an existing API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there any outage when you add a second region to an existing API Management?

We've gone live with API Management in a single region, but we now want to improve availability by adding a second region

But we're concerned there may be an outage

Checked [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region) but can't see anything on potential effects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no outage when you are going to add a new region or remove that region. That is handled seamlessly.

However there will be outage if you scale down to Developer SKU from Premium SKU,  as the Developer SKU is only 1 VM.